# nrfjprog permission issue in clion IDE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, clion, nrf52

I am using the nrf52 from nordic semiconductor on Mac ox. setup is done and working great using this [method](https://github.com/Polidea/cmake-nRF5x)

I am facing issue during the flash using IDE. of course I am using nrfjprog for flashing. nrfjprog is working with

terminal but not with clion IDE.

here is output

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/atifshabbir/Development/git/Blinky/cmake-build-default --target FLASH_Blinky -- -j 2
[ 96%] Built target Blinky
[100%] flashing Blinky.hex

make[3]: /Users/atifshabbir/Development/nrfjprog: Permission denied

make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/FLASH_Blinky] Error 1

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/FLASH_Blinky.dir/all] Error 2

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/FLASH_Blinky.dir/rule] Error 2

make: *** [FLASH_Blinky] Error 2
```

here are the permission to nrfjprog folder

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 atifshabbir  staff    7946 Dec  1 11:23 DllCommonDefinitions.h

-rw-r--r--@ 1 atifshabbir  staff    2161 Dec  1 11:23 QspiDefault.ini

-rw-r--r--@ 1 atifshabbir  staff   58616 Dec  1 11:23 highlevelnrfjprogdll.h

-rw-r--r--@ 1 atifshabbir  staff  106943 Dec  1 11:23 jlinkarm_nrf51_nrfjprogdll.h

-rw-r--r--@ 1 atifshabbir  staff  129570 Dec  1 11:23 jlinkarm_nrf52_nrfjprogdll.h

-rw-r--r--@ 1 atifshabbir  staff   34753 Dec  1 11:23 jlinkarm_unknown_nrfjprogdll.h

-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff  434596 Dec  1 11:23 libhighlevelnrfjprog.9.7.2.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff      32 Dec  1 11:23 libhighlevelnrfjprog.9.dylib -> libhighlevelnrfjprog.9.7.2.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff      28 Dec  1 11:23 libhighlevelnrfjprog.dylib -> libhighlevelnrfjprog.9.dylib

-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff  207848 Dec  1 11:23 libjlinkarm_nrf51_nrfjprogdll.9.7.2.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff      41 Dec  1 11:23 libjlinkarm_nrf51_nrfjprogdll.9.dylib -> libjlinkarm_nrf51_nrfjprogdll.9.7.2.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff      37 Dec  1 11:23 libjlinkarm_nrf51_nrfjprogdll.dylib -> libjlinkarm_nrf51_nrfjprogdll.9.dylib

-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff  282236 Dec  1 11:23 libjlinkarm_nrf52_nrfjprogdll.9.7.2.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff      41 Dec  1 11:23 libjlinkarm_nrf52_nrfjprogdll.9.dylib -> libjlinkarm_nrf52_nrfjprogdll.9.7.2.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff      37 Dec  1 11:23 libjlinkarm_nrf52_nrfjprogdll.dylib -> libjlinkarm_nrf52_nrfjprogdll.9.dylib

-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff   83640 Dec  1 11:23 libjlinkarm_unknown_nrfjprogdll.9.7.2.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff      43 Dec  1 11:23 libjlinkarm_unknown_nrfjprogdll.9.dylib -> libjlinkarm_unknown_nrfjprogdll.9.7.2.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff      39 Dec  1 11:23 libjlinkarm_unknown_nrfjprogdll.dylib -> libjlinkarm_unknown_nrfjprogdll.9.dylib

-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff   77024 Dec  1 11:23 libnrfjprogdll.9.7.2.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff      26 Dec  1 11:23 libnrfjprogdll.9.dylib -> libnrfjprogdll.9.7.2.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff      22 Dec  1 11:23 libnrfjprogdll.dylib -> libnrfjprogdll.9.dylib

-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 atifshabbir  staff  573092 Dec  1 11:23 nrfjprog

-rw-r--r--@ 1 atifshabbir  staff    6835 Dec  1 11:23 nrfjprog.h

-rw-r--r--@ 1 atifshabbir  staff     611 Dec  1 11:23 nrfjprog.ini

-rw-r--r--@ 1 atifshabbir  staff   55140 Dec  1 11:23 nrfjprog_release_notes.txt

-rw-r--r--@ 1 atifshabbir  staff   14647 Dec  1 11:23 nrfjprogdll.h
```

is this IDE need some kind of permission to use the nrfjprog folder because terminal have no issue to flash.

Comment: This is a Unix/Linux permission based question and it should have a tag that reflects that. You would have got a fast response if you had so.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all the users to have permission to execute nrfjprog

`sudo chmod a+x <path-to-nrfjprog>/nrfjprog`

That should make it runnable for all users. Then try re-executing the flashing program.